# Merging more than 9 input files with lasmerge?

Tags: qgis, merge, lidar, las, lastools

Is there a possibility to feed more than 9 LAS files to `lasmerge` tool? The user interface only allows 9 LAS files from LAStools toolboxes in QGIS or ArcGIS, but at liblas.org it’s described as there can also be a text file holding the file names to be merged.

Unfortunately it’s not said how to format the text file and my attempts in Python with the absolute path of each file per line fails.

Comment: You have tags for QGIS, ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcPy but how do they relate to your question?

Comment: lasmerge is available in the toolboxes of both, QGIS and ArcGIS. No matter which of the two programs I am using, the user interface offers only 9 input file options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more documentation available from [here](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasmerge_README.txt) .

It includes additional examples, among them:

```
lasmerge -i *.las -o out0000.las -split 1000000000
```

> merge all *.las files into one and then split it into several
>     output files that contain one billion points each and that are
>     called out0000.las, out0001.las, out0002.las, out0003.las, ...