# Merging multiple las files?

Tags: merge, lidar, software-recommendations, las, lastools

I want to merge 10 las files into one, and I am having problems with lasmerge of lastools. It isn't able to deal with such a high number of points (average of points per file almost 4 million of points).

Does anybody know other way to merge multiple las files into one? Other softwares or perhaps some python code?

---

I realised that there was not an error, simply the lasmerge put the new merged file into the bin folder, not in the specified folder.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164377/merging-more-than-9-input-files-with-lasmerge/164379#164379

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are any `lasmerge` errors it should work fine.

Believe me, 40 million points is nothing.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Finally I realised that there was not an error, simply the lasmerge puts the new merged file into the bin folder, not in the specified folder.

Comment: Yes there it is. That why i move Las exe files to folders where i have LiDAR data and i run it from there. Great that you solved it