# Merging multiple LiDAR (.las) files using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, tiles, lidar

I downloaded about 9 LiDAR scenes from USGS and I want to use ArcMap to merge them so that I can carry out tasks on them together as opposed to one by one.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what software you have or are prepared to obtain. In ArcGIS there is a concept of a LAS Dataset https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//015w0000005r000000 that will incorporate all LAS files into a single dataset. If you do not have ArcGIS you could try LASTools LAS2LAS -i *.las -o c:\your\path\Output.las to merge the files into a single las file https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/las2las/. Note that neither of these packages are free but LASTools is cheaper, significantly so if you're a student or researcher, and has more tools for visualizing LAS data.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using ArcMap. Creating the dataset worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tasks are indeed better off processing tiles altogether so to avoid 'edge artifacts' (like creating a DEM).

In this case, work with tiles using tools that can process them on-the-fly, like **ArcGIS**. Create a [LAS Dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/creating-a-las-dataset.htm) and work form there. For example: [Converting LiDAR data to raster (DEM/DSM) for ArcGIS input?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/converting-lidar-data-to-raster-dem-dsm-for-arcgis-input/56710#56710).

Or work on a full merged file. For example, with `MergeData` tool from [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html):.

```
C:\Fusion\MergeData C:\lidar_data\*.las C:\lidar_data\output\alldata_merged.las
```

This will merge all .las files in directory `C:\lidar_data`, and will create a merged file named `alldata_merged.las` in the subfolder `output`.

---

Another option is [larmerge](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasmerge_README.txt) from LAStools. See: [Merging more than 9 input files with lasmerge?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164377/merging-more-than-9-input-files-with-lasmerge/164379#164379). LAStools can also merge files on-the-fly; take a look at examples from [las2dem](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2dem_README.txt) (search the switch `-merged`).

Still about LAStools, one can also use [buffered tiles](https://rapidlasso.com/2015/08/07/use-buffers-when-processing-lidar-in-tiles/) (also to avoid 'edge artifacts') while speeding up processing through parallel core usage.