# Merging LiDAR files using R

Tags: r, merge, lidar, usgs

I am downloading LiDAR files (.laz) from https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/#/.

How can I merge multiple files together using R?

Note that this related to [Merging multiple LiDAR (.las) files using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297745), but it has to do with another software.

Comment: You could have a look at the R package [LidR](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/) with an excellent tutorial. The section 14 (LASCataloge) shows you advanced techniques to hande large LAS-mosaics.